# Android AppWidget layout troubles with ellipsize

Tags: android, layout, android-appwidget

I'm writing an app-widget that displays some numbers, each with label in front of it.

The layout looks like this:

```
.-----------------------------.
| Label1       |  AAAAAAAAAAA |
| LongerLabelLabel2 | BBBBBBB |
| LongLabel3    | CCCCCCCCCC  |
'-----------------------------'
```

There is one outer (vertical) LinearLayout, and each row is a horizontal LinearLayout with two TextViews.

The problem is that the *numbers* get ellipsized if the width of the label and the number is too wide for the widget. I want the *labels* to get ellipsized.

The above situation for instance, would end up like this:

```
.-----------------------------.
| Label1    |     AAAAAAAAAAA |
| LongerLabelLabel2 | BBBB... |
| LongLabel3 |    CCCCCCCCCC  |
'-----------------------------'
```

instead of the desired

```
.---------------------------.
| Label1     |  AAAAAAAAAAA |
| LongerLabelL... | BBBBBBB |
| LongLabel3  | CCCCCCCCCC  |
'---------------------------'
```

I can't for my life figure out how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

---

My current layout is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/WidgetBackground">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:id="@+id/ROW1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingTop="7dip"
              android:paddingBottom="0dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/NAME1" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ellipsize="end" style="@style/Text.account" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/BAL1"  android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" style="@style/Text.balance" />
    </LinearLayout>

... (more similar rows in the outer layout)

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you considered using the attribute `android:ellipsize="3"` in your xml (I suppose you do, but I prefer asking)? Maybe you could also use `android:inputType ="textMultiLine"`

Comment: @CommonsWare, sorry for the late answer; Of course! Question updated. (This is still driving me nuts!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem, in part, is that you have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for your label. I would not expect it to ellipsize at all, since there is enough room to show it.

I would switch away from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. Define your number "column" as `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Define your label "column" as `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:layout_toLeftOf="..."` (where `...` is your number column), and `android:ellpsize="end"`. That should give the number all the space it needs and constrain the label, forcing it to ellipsize.

Comment: Ah.. I looked at RelativeLayout but couldn't figure out how to do it... I'll give it a shot with your instructions. Thanks!